# PHP - Foreach While Loop - Email Client and Update database for each stock (quantity) they enter

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have been stuck on this for a while now and can't seem to figure it out.

I am running quantity in an int, for example, 5.

I want to loop through each quantity until the max quantity is reached, max being the quantity they enter starting from 0.

This is my query to get the stocks items:

```
$product_id = '1';
$quantity = '2';

$smtp_main = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `productitems` WHERE `avaliable` = :avaliable AND `assignedProduct` = :assignedProduct LIMIT :limit');
$smtp_main->execute(array(':avaliable' => '0', ':assignedProduct' => $product_id, ':limit' => $quantity));

$query = $smtp_main->fetchAll();
```

Then this is my current while loop / foreach loop:

```
        // Foreach loop here
        $i = 0;
        $maxiterations = $quantity;

        while($i <= $maxiterations) {
            foreach($query as $row_product) {
                $product_link_stock = $row_product['code'];
                $stock_id_stock = $row_product['id'];
            }

            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email/Username:Pass(".$i."):</strong> </td><td>".$product_link_stock."</td></tr>";
            $i++;

            // Update stock foreach stock product they require (quantity depends on this)
            $updateStock = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `productitems` SET `avaliable` = :avaliable WHERE `id` = :id');
            $updateStock->execute(array(':avaliable' => '1', ':id' => $stock_id_stock));
        }
```

Then my mail function is outside of both loops and it sends mail with no problem.

The error I am getting is that the stock is only going down by 1 and it is not showing 2 stocks in the email I get - [image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then $row_product contain multiple products, and you update only last one, because $message, $i and $updateStock are out of foreach loop.
Try to put that code inside foreach loop.

However I would suggest to avoid nesting loops, and use only one foreach. Because, you update stocks available to 1, multiple times, which makes no sense.

For generating $message you can use str_repeat() function

> Update

```
foreach($query as $i => $row_product) {
   $product_link_stock = $row_product['code'];
   $stock_id_stock = $row_product['id'];
   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email/Username:Pass(".$i."):</strong> </td><td>".$product_link_stock."</td></tr>";

   $updateStock = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `productitems` SET `avaliable` = :avaliable WHERE `id` = :id');
   $updateStock->execute(array(':avaliable' => '1', ':id' => $stock_id_stock));        

}
```

Comment: can you show me what my answer should look like then, please?

Comment: No, I want it to update each stock that it selects from the database so the user cannot buy the same stock.

Comment: look at this update. If your query get that stocks, than you will update (or do whatever you want) with each of them

Comment: It seems to be getting all the stocks now. Look - https://i.gyazo.com/c878daab6bcbd06bc45ec78bc7108e3a